# UITableView section header 1px gloss/shadow overlapping

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, scroll

Here's how standard section header views handle scrolling/overlaping:

[image]

I'm trying to replicate the same behavior with custom section headers but all I get is this:

[image]

It seems that in the default behavior, the top 1px line of the bottom header view overlaps the bottom 1px line of the top header view. This can also be observed below the navbar, where that same top 1px line disappears underneath it.

Setting a contentInset on the tableview fixes the navbar situation, but not the overlapping issue. I've also tried playing with the maskToBounds and clipToBounds properties, but no luck. Any clue?

Comment: It looks as though you are also getting the 1 pixel overlap. What's happening to the medium gray pixel line right above the dark blue?

Comment: Sorry, probably should have mentioned: that gray pixel line is part of my custom cell view. Screenshot of custom cell with default header view: http://samv.me/4vpF

Comment: This seems like one of those things an Apple designer complained about and engineering hacked around with private API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Adams mentioned, there doesn't seem to be any public API to deal with this, so in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method I did something along these lines:

```
if(isLastCellInSection)
    cell.drawBottomLine = NO;
else
    cell.drawBottomLine = YES;
```